# Add a new language to Bonita Studio

Tags: bonita

I want to Add the Persian Language to Bonita Community 7.3.For Bonita Portal, it is so easy. I download the ".po" file from translation website then I put it in i18n folder and it works well. But For Studio section, there are some ".properties" files. The Bonita Studio works based on Eclipse Babel technology.I don't know how to add a new language to Bonita Studio?
There is a translation module in Source code of Studio Section and How can I add my language to it?

Any suggestion is acceptable.

Best Regard.
REZA